# Cmake add link dll when I run .*.exe

Tags: cmake

I have a .*.dll. My .*.exe must include this dll file.

I have seen this link [How to use external DLLs in CMake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225121/how-to-use-external-dlls-in-cmake-project), but this is correct for me.

How to add search dll path in cmake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Comment: If you bother about finding a `.dll` library at **runtime**, then either the library should be in system location or it should be in the same directory as executable itself. There are many question on Stack Overflow about copying `.dll` into the directory with `.exe` in CMake.