# CMake - Define dlls directory or files for a generated project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I have a project that I am building using `CMake` for `Visual Studio`.
The `.exe` file requires 2 dll files (That I am copying to the Debug forlder for now).

Is there a way to add the **dlls**/ **dlls directory** through **`CMakeLists.txt`** / **`FindLibrary.cmake`**
 (the same way it's done with find_library to find `*.lib` or in some other way that I ignore) so that I **don't copy** them **MANUALLY** **inside** the **Debug** **folder** each time I generate the project in another folder/pc (since the dll's folder is known)?

### UPDATE :

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
..
..
set (ENVLIB $ENV{MYLIB})
FUNCTION (CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER TARGET_NAME)
  CONFIGURE_FILE(common/build/template/Main.vcxproj.user
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.vcxproj.user
    @ONLY
    )
ENDFUNCTION (CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER)
..
..
ADD_EXECUTABLE(Main Main.cxx)
CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER(Main)
```

**Main.vcxproj.user**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=@ENVLIB@bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Additional PropertyGroups for the rest of Configuration/Platform combos -->

</Project>
```

**Output of vcxproj.user after generation**
`<LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=C:\Program Files\MyLib\bin;$(Path)`

The variable `ENVLIB` has been changed to the correct PATH when the file has been copied but 
Visual studio is still asking for those DLLs. It's like it is ignoring the file `.vcxproj.user`

## SOLVED :

Solved changed the property : `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">` to 
`<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">`

Comment: Question, why don't you put them in a folder that you then add to the PATH environment variable instead? Not a long term solution maybe and leaving your question still relevant, but as a short term solution? Aside from that, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225121/how-to-use-external-dlls-in-cmake-project answer your question?

Comment: For the simple reason that I want it to be less work for others. Only if there's a way to add to the PATH environment variable from `CMakeLists.txt` / `FindLibrary.cmake` that would be good for me

Comment: Option 1: Make a custom target that runs a CMake script that copies the necessary files. Option 2: Generate (using `CONFIGURE_FILE`) a `.vcxproj.user` file that sets up `LocalDebuggerEnvironment` such that the directory with the DLLs is added to the `PATH`. (This is my preference, since I can also set up working directory and command line arguments to pass to the debugged application)

Comment: You can use `find_file()` and `add_custom_command()` to copy the `.dll` to the folder `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}`.

Comment: Gonna check both solutions (Dan & @Fred) as soon as possible ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option would be to create a custom target, that will run a CMake script to copy the files.

The second option (which I prefer) is to use `CONFIGURE_FILE` to generate a `.vcxproj.user` file, which set up `LocalDebuggerEnvironment` such that the directory with the DLLs is added to the PATH.

For example, my build system defines a function `CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER`:

```
FUNCTION(CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER TARGET_NAME)
  CONFIGURE_FILE(${ROOT}/common/build/template/executable_vs14.vcxproj.user
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.vcxproj.user
    @ONLY
    )
ENDFUNCTION(CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER)
```

I call this function right after I define an executable target, e.g.

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(example
  ${EXAMPLE__SRC}
  ${EXAMPLE__HDR}
)
CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER(example)
```

The template `executable_vs14.vcxproj.user` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Additional PropertyGroups for the rest of Configuration/Platform combos -->

</Project>
```

---

Note: In the above example, I also set some default command arguments to run the app with when debugging as well as the working directory where it runs -- adjust things as you need.

Note 2: Now that I'm looking at it, perhaps we can change the `Condition` on the `PropertyGroup` to make it apply to every configuration/platform. Gotta look into that.

Comment: I am going to test it in some time, Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Calips Yeah, if you need them there at the time of generating the solution, rather than after the compilation, then this won't help.

Comment: Now that I think about it, in my case it isn't possible to use that, the reason is simple : I am using a `FindLibrary.cmake` file which for now uses an environment variable as `HINTS`(in `find_path()` and `find_library()`) to find the library directory (which contains the DLLs/bin folder). And since the `CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER` needs to be placed after `ADD_EXECUTABLE`, it's already late.

Comment: Supposing I can just use the DLLs later and keep The environment variable which points to the root of the library that has : `include`, `lib` and `bin` folders, can it be used to replace `SolutionDir` in : `<LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)` something like `<LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=@ENV ${VARIABLE_NAME}@\bin;$(Path)` ?

Comment: @Calips I think so, using the substitution capabilities of `CONFIGURE_FILE`. Not sure if you can use environment variable directly, but that shouldn't be a bit issue to overcome (just load it into regular CMake var).

Comment: Please Check the update section and tell me if there is anything I am missing ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved changed the property : `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">` to `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">`

Comment: Thanks for the support @Dan