# How do I link a library using CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to add a new library to a project built using CMake and am having trouble. I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225121/how-to-use-external-dlls-in-cmake-project). I've made a test project that looks like this:

```
cmake_test/
    test.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
    liblsl/
        include/
            lsl_cpp.h
        CMakeLists.txt
        liblsl64.dll
        liblsl64.so
    build/
```

the CMakeLists.txt in cmake_test looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name and version
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(Tutorial test.cpp)
add_subdirectory(liblsl)
target_link_libraries(Tutorial PUBLIC ${LSL_LIBRARY})
```

and the CMakeLists.txt in liblsl looks like this:

```
find_path(LSL_INCLUDE_DIR lsl_cpp.h)
find_library(LSL_LIBRARY liblsl64)
include_directories(${LSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

But I keep getting the error `No rule to make target '.../liblsl64.lib', needed by 'Tutorial.exe'. Stop.`
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I'm on Windows 10 using mingw-w64 v5.4.0 if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is content of `LSL_LIBRARY` variable at the time you use it for linking? If it points to `.dll`, then you need corresponded `.lib` (not a static library but an "export" file) for being able to perform the link. This is what the error message is talking about.

Comment: I had it set up with LSL_LIBRARY pointing to the .lib file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMakeLists.txt` in `cmake_test`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(liblsl)

add_executable(Tutorial test.cpp)
target_compile_features(Tutorial PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_link_libraries(Tutorial PUBLIC liblsl)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` in `liblsl`:

```
add_library(liblsl SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(liblsl PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set_target_properties(liblsl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/liblsl64.so")
```

For Windows use:

```
set_target_properties(liblsl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/liblsl64.dll")
set_target_properties(liblsl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/liblsl64.lib")
```

In [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html), you say `SHARED` because your library is a shared one (`so`/`dll`), you say `IMPORTED` because you don't want to build the library, and you say `GLOBAL` because you want it to be visible outside `liblsl`.